# timezone - push notification

Tags: iphone, timezone, apple-push-notifications

I want to add a feature that enables users of my app to turn off notifications between a interval in a day.

What's the best way to store that interval(different timezones to be considered) and send push notifications accordingly - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check `NSTimeZone` to retreive the timezone, send it to the server, and adjust the sending of notifications by checking the timezone of users.